# set_intersection with a custom set comparator

Tags: c++, c++11

When I use the std::set_intersection function with a set that has custom comparator I don't get the expected result. 
The follow code outputs that {5,9,7} intersect {9} is empty set. However if I just use the normal comparator I get {9}.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <set>

using namespace std;
auto cmp = [](int* a, int* b) { return a < b; };
using stupid_set = set<int*, decltype(cmp)>;
int main() {
    int* n5 = new int(5);
    int* n9 = new int(9);
    int* n7 = new int(7);
    stupid_set s0 {n5, n9, n7};
    stupid_set s1 {n9};
    stupid_set i;
    for (auto s:s0) {
        cout << "s0:" << *s << endl;
    }
    for (auto s:s1) {
        cout << "s1:" << *s << endl;
    }
    set_intersection(s0.begin(), s0.end(), s1.begin(), s1.end(), std::inserter(i, i.begin()));
    for (auto x : i) {
        cout << "Int=" << *x << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your comparator compares pointers, which is an **undefined operation** up to some special cases (pointers to array elements or non-static member variables of the same access rights). See [expr.rel/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.rel#4).

Comment: Note that `std::less<int*>` *doesn't* just call `<`

Comment: `std::less<int*>` is *specified* to not just call `<` but in practice it actually [does](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_function.h#L441) (of course it does).

Comment: @rustyx look closer: it's only doing that for consteval pointers, otherwise it uses `uintptr_t`'s `<`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code, but the core one is that you use a custom comparator for sets, but not for `std::set_intersection` function call. This function also needs to compare elements, and, of course, must compare them with the same comparator.

Use:

```
struct cmp 
{
  bool operator()(int* a, int* b) const { return *a < *b; };
};

using stupid_set = set<int*, cmp>;
```

and

```
set_intersection(
 s0.begin(), s0.end(),
 s1.begin(), s1.end(),
 std::inserter(i, i.begin()),
 cmp{}  // custom comparator used for sets
);
```

Whole live demo is here: https://godbolt.org/z/OAr3xV.

---

Note that if you omit the comparator, `std::set_intersection` will use `operator<` for set elements, and this operation is **generally undefined for pointers**.

If you really want to compare pointers and not the integer values there point to, you need to use `std::less`, since this defines order even for pointers in general:

```
struct cmp 
{
  bool operator()(int* a, int* b) const { return std::less<int*>{}(a, b); };
};
```

Again, you need to pass this comparator to `std::set_intersection` as well.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/tLdfqn.

Comment: Nitpick: it does not directly use `operator<`, it uses `std::less`, which is well-defined for unrelated pointers.

Comment: @rustyx Then, cppreference is wrong here, since it says that [it uses `operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) if `comp` is omitted.

Comment: The current [Standard](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) says in the introduction to Chapter 28.7 Sorting and related operations: "All the operations […] have two versions: one that takes a function object of type `Compare` and one that uses an `operator<`. The default template parameter of `std::less` is only introduced for the algorithms of the same name in `std::ranges` (cf. [P0896](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0896r4.pdf) sect. 24.7.6.3).

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing compare function passed to the `std::set` and `std::set_intersection`. When passed to the `std::set`, `Compare` function is used for sorting because it is key comparison function. When passed to `std::set_intersection` it is used to define an intersection.

Try following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

struct cmp {
   bool operator()(int *a, int *b) const {
      return *a < *b;
   }
};

using stupid_set = std::set<int*, cmp>;

int main() {
    int* n5 = new int(5);
    int* n9 = new int(9);
    int* n7 = new int(7);

    stupid_set s0 {n5, n9, n7};
    stupid_set s1 {n9};
    stupid_set i;

    for (auto s : s0) {
        std::cout << "s0:" << *s << std::endl;
    }

    for (auto s:s1) {
        std::cout << "s1:" << *s << std::endl;
    }

    std::set_intersection(
        s0.begin(),
        s0.end(),
        s1.begin(),
        s1.end(),
        std::inserter(i, i.begin()),
        cmp()
    );

    for (auto x : i) {
        std::cout << "Int=" << *x << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Check [live](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxEAFZSAB1QLC62nsMTQS8fNTorG3sjJxd3JRUw2gYCZmICAONTTkVlTFU/ZNSCCLtHZzdFFLSMoOyFKuLrUujy1wBKRVQDYmQOAHIpAGZrZEMsAGpxQZ11euJMZiMp7HEABgBBIZGxzEnp5Hr0VjwHZbXNyWHaUYMJqZ0lAjONreudvZ02YBJCBCXBlYvDZzAyqcbIIweSYAdlkG3GCIcqH041QHmczCIxAgbQg1gI4wAVMxSON8USHG1wXR6jC4esEYzxvMCN1aETmB8KVN6YzxNCACLnflCwb084GHyicb1AwePDoAD6jz2AplBHQIBAj3u%2BMJpIhHjOYuFG3JRmY1hxdPOTL141orlVDswAHcyfQIO0ebbGfbaABOZ02d34iABto%2B%2BF%2B%2BiEh3Q4Nuj0ECDQyMmoEMxmy%2BVKlUKVZ0x2kwMl6EiqNZhE5hXKzAEhScIsBisZqvquW1lV4Su%2BhE0YjjCDMAxEGXjEAy1ZU/m8pnZjVatCjj73SaSSQFkBSSSr6ZEhR7nTqzUgcysStMiuZpkDocjscKbWcGewvvzw5LroE%2B5rneN7cNyPA9gM/M9tAvNsr0FU12zAx5FXxZwlHyOgIALAA6JxgCtDopww8wcVJRssMwHDaCImVOAI7RKLA6wlDSZw8VJPBSPInE8MNTje2jfsSHvUdUHGAAPCcyVfOd5xPL8V1/fcdwASXoKYhSA%2BTj0JMSNJk8CjkvPkYJeQU%2Bg6VgQD6Vw%2BlIUw%2BlWazUAsnQ5DkGUuh6XYhk4ayCAs%2By2g6ABrEBuADDDBm4aFJFcAAObgYtcAA2QYA0SgMhAs7hrNs%2BzSEcvprKfVZSF8uzTNIOBYBgRAUFQSE8HYMgKAgNB6sakBgADSRSCoBqCGQygHD86yHGsVIAE8LO80hWqMLQCAAeVoVhJrK0gsAtUR2GG9a8HmfIADdMCfNbMBEvJR36XKkPMtbjgcYgJr0LApp84g8CMV6OhoegmDYDgeH4QRhFEFAXJkIQTifSAOjRRIToAWkOVSJBkOROGhQrclQ0wIHMGoslIcwSiiGJgm8Xw6AJ8nQj8EmyhcOpscSQpqn0TJBHiPIWYaemWkZyoimpupeaaUnyhfTpul6LgzIsqybJ2/KRJixKEcS7hxmAZBkHGMLdwgXBCAErzST0NrnHXQYX3GZy0ZkHzhoC0hgtcQYMOhbhJBi1LBkGVx4p9wYMr6LLSE%2B1xipyhyLMKkBitK/yKuqiAkG/DxR3IShWvldrskwfAsUEH7GBYbbAddR6PC%2BkOFejvKLK88ZXV%2BUTVfVzXtd1/XHbK52EAWLAXCI26w4jqOldjxR45Kp2grcVYMMS1xJE9zhXB4QZEtWa2Q8GbLJ4K2e%2B7lvpJAPtb8t7/yOiO4gfA0bggA%3D)

Comment: This does not seem to work. In your live demo, `i` is empty.

Comment: I think I found the issue. We need to use <= instead of < :
auto cmp = [](int* a, int* b) { return  a <= b; };

Comment: @HajAyedAmir No, you didn't. A comparator with `a <= b` [does not meet the requirement for comparators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare).